# How to Revoke Execute Privileges on Functions in PostgreSQL by Default

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I am trying to set up default privileges in PostgreSQL 9.5.4 using the command `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES...`.  This works when trying to grant permissions, but I can't figure out how to revoke execute permissions from functions by default.  I have tried:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR USER myAdmin IN SCHEMA public
    REVOKE EXECUTE ON FUNCTIONS FROM public;
```

This appears to have no effect on the output of `\ddp`.  Is there a way to prevent functions from being executable by users other than the owner, unless otherwise granted?  Thanks.

Comment: What role(s) does `public` currently belong to?

Comment: @Nicarus I'm fairly new to PostgreSQL roles, and therefore don't understand your question.  I have tried the same command, but replaced the final `public` identifier with a specific user's name.  That also has no effect on the output of `\ddp`.

Comment: Run this: `SELECT * FROM pg_roles WHERE rolename = 'public';` You should be able to see the privs. and roles for that role. An example would be the role is `superuser` and therefore you altering the privs would not have an impact.

Comment: @Nicarus That select statement (I had to change `rolename` to `rolname`) returned 0 rows.  It is my understanding that 'public' is a built-in keyword meaning all users.  Is that not correct?

Comment: It is built-in, but I thought you'd still be able to see the privs. Sorry about that - (I'm at work and cannot test on PG)

Comment: Strange... Seems to work without the `IN SCHEMA public`, though I have no idea what the difference is...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you specify `IN SCHEMA` with `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES`, you can only *grant* permissions, but not *revoke* them.

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html) says:

> Default privileges that are specified per-schema are added to whatever the global default privileges are for the particular object type.

Therefore, you must revoke from the global default privileges by changing your command to:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR USER myAdmin
    REVOKE EXECUTE ON FUNCTIONS FROM public;
```

Answer (score 0):

I can use "FOR ROLE"?

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE myAdmin
    REVOKE EXECUTE ON FUNCTIONS FROM public;
```